# Nombre correcto en castellano para el símbolo &

Tags: definiciones, extranjerismos, curiosidades

Este impronunciable símbolo de nombre inglés **"ampersand"** lo he oído hispanizado como *"ámperson"* o sencillamente "y". Sin embargo, me parece curioso dado el origen sajón del símbolo, (solía recitarse con el alfabeto, colocándolo después de la "Z" y la fórmula escolarizada terminaba como *"... X, Y, Z, **and per se 'and'** (&)"* (x,y,z y por sí mismo "y")).

¿Se ha pronunciado la RAE al respecto? Es indudable que la adopción de este símbolo como operador de lógica Boleana en ciencias de la computación hace que de alguna manera tengamos que referirnos a él.

Comment: _et_, y en inglés _ampersand_. Fundéu: [&, nombre de este signo gráfico](http://www.fundeu.es/consulta/nombre-de-este-signo-grafico-2714/)